# Subquery returned more than 1 value from look up table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

I am having this error on my query. I have a look up table that stores the value of gender, marital status and customer type. But I want to display all in 1 grid view in asp. It is work if there is only 1 record on the database, but when I save another record the error appears.Can someone suggest a fix?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  customer.customer_id
  ,customer.first_name
 ,customer.last_name
 ,customer.birth_date
 ,customer.phone
 ,customer.email
 ,customer.block
 ,customer.lot
 ,customer.status
 ,customer.is_deleted
 ,(SELECT 
 lookup_table.value
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
INNER JOIN dbo.customer ON customer.gender = lookup_table.lookup_id) AS Gender
 ,(SELECT 
 lookup_table.value
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
INNER JOIN dbo.customer ON customer.marital_status = lookup_table.lookup_id) AS MaritalStatus
 ,(SELECT 
 lookup_table.value
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
INNER JOIN dbo.customer ON customer.village = lookup_table.lookup_id) AS Village
 ,(SELECT 
 lookup_table.value
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
INNER JOIN dbo.customer ON customer.customer_type = lookup_table.lookup_id) AS CustomerType
FROM dbo.customer
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give us some sample data with the corresponding result?

Comment: You can apply LEFT JOIN of all the condition mention in ( )  with table dbo.customer  and select only relevant column.

Comment: @SureshGajera LEFT JOIN does not work. The error is this there

Comment: what is the table dbo.lookup_description used for? it is not being used to pull data.

Comment: @ankyskywalker Its for the Category Where Gender, Village, Customer type are stored. The look up table is where the values are store where male,female, etc are stored

Comment: @miguel but you are not using the table in either pulling data nor filtering data, so it is really necessary. I am solely going by the query you posted.

Comment: I am talking about applying LEFT JOIN at the end and not within (). Please refer query submitted by @ankyskywalker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense that you have this error. With one record all is fine, but your subquery have more values with more records and the ngine doesnt know what to choose.
Because you are not filtering at all, you want all customer with their characteritics (gender, village...)
You should do something like this i beleive:

```
SELECT
  customer.customer_id
  ,customer.first_name
 ,customer.last_name
 ,customer.birth_date
 ,customer.phone
 ,customer.email
 ,customer.block
 ,customer.lot
 ,customer.status
 ,customer.is_deleted
 ,Gender
 ,marital_status
 ,village
 ,customer_type

FROM dbo.customer a
inner join
 (SELECT 
 lookup_table.value as Gender, lookup_id
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
 ) AS Gender on  a.gender = Gender.lookup_id

inner join
 (SELECT 
 lookup_table.value as marital_status, lookup_id
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
 ) AS marital_status on  a.marital_status = marital_status.lookup_id

inner join
 (SELECT 
 lookup_table.value as village, lookup_id
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
 ) AS village on  a.village = village.lookup_id

inner join
 (SELECT 
 lookup_table.value as customer_type, lookup_id
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
 ) AS customer_type on  a.customer_type = customer_type.lookup_id
```

Comment: This query does not recognize the dbo.customer as an object

Comment: what is the error you are getting from that query Miguel?

Comment: @Miguel, it should work now... I added the alias of dbo.customer in the query. Let me know

Comment: Error on this dbo.customer a

Comment: Hi @zip your query worked. I just replaced customer. above with 'a' and removed Gender,marital_status,village,customer_type. Will post my answer. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @zip, the subquery returns multiple rows and creates an issue, you can try something like this and apply filters to eliminate duplicates

```
SELECT
  customer.customer_id
 ,customer.first_name
 ,customer.last_name
 ,customer.birth_date
 ,customer.phone
 ,customer.email
 ,customer.block
 ,customer.lot
 ,customer.status
 ,customer.is_deleted
 ,gender.value AS Gender
 ,MaritalStatus.value AS MaritalStatus
 ,Village.value AS Village
 ,CustomerType.value AS CustomerType
FROM dbo.customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.lookup_table gender          ON customer.gender = gender.lookup_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.lookup_table MaritalStatus   ON customer.marital_status = MaritalStatus.lookup_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.lookup_table Village         ON customer.village = Village.lookup_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.lookup_table CustomerType    ON customer.customer_type = CustomerType.lookup_id
```

Comment: Error on this line FROM dbo.customer

Comment: There was no space between value and  AS at Village column in select list

Comment: I dont know but there is still an error in this line (FROM dbo.customer )

Answer (score 0):

I followed zip's answer. He made an customer table as 'a'. Replaced customer with 'a' and removed Gender,marital_status,village,customer_type.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
  a.customer_id
  ,a.first_name
 ,a.last_name
 ,a.birth_date
 ,a.phone
 ,a.email
 ,a.block
 ,a.lot
 ,a.status
 ,a.is_deleted

FROM dbo.customer a
inner join
 (SELECT 
 lookup_table.value as Gender, lookup_id
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
 ) AS Gender on  a.gender = Gender.lookup_id

inner join
 (SELECT 
 lookup_table.value as marital_status, lookup_id
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
 ) AS marital_status on  a.marital_status = marital_status.lookup_id

inner join
 (SELECT 
 lookup_table.value as village, lookup_id
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
 ) AS village on  a.village = village.lookup_id

inner join
 (SELECT 
 lookup_table.value as customer_type, lookup_id
FROM dbo.lookup_description
INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_table
  ON lookup_description.desc_id = lookup_table.group_id
 ) AS customer_type on  a.customer_type = customer_type.lookup_id
```

Comment: But this query does not display the columns village,customer_type,marital_status and gender